# Cannot set Sencha GXT window size

Tags: gwt, window, gxt

I'm playing with the Sencha GXT desktopapp example. Tried all methods below to change the window size. But when I open the window, the size is not what I set.

```java
window.setWidth(500);
window.setHeight(400);
window.setBodyStyle("width:500px;height:400px;background-color:red;");
window.setPixelSize(500, 400);
window.getElement().setSize(500, 400, true);
window.setMinHeight(400);
window.setMinWidth(500);
window.forceLayout();
```

The version is gxt-3.0.1-GPL

Comment: What size are you aiming for? (the min height and width overrule your setted width & height ...)

Comment: I'm aiming for a bigger size which is bigger than the default which I believe is 400. I tried all the combinations. None of them works.

Comment: window.setSize(1110, 610); try this it may work.